# Title shows 3 dots "..." instead of the string in a toggle button

Tags: ios, objective-c

Strange behaviour. Im trying to make toggle button that changes the title of the button.
But instead of "Done" it shows me "..." :

[image]

The method:

```
-(IBAction)toggleEditingMode:(id)sender
{
    if(self.isEditing){
        [sender setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
    else if(!self.isEditing){
        [sender setTitle: @"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the size of the button? Could you enlarge it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's truncating, either button needs to be bigger, or text needs to be smaller.

To adjust text dynamically,

```
yourButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
yourButton.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can add this code after set Barberton item. It works fine.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```