# ios7 navigation bar : 3 strange dots appearing when back animation with custom button

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I would like to use the back navigation animation using

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

with a custom button added to the navigation bar.

As I don't want the back button to be seen, i've hidden it with     `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;`

But during the back animation, on ios7 (not ios6) 3 dots can be seen sliding in the navigation bar.
They are not appearing with `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;` but of course the button can be seen.

Does anyone has any idea to make them not appearing ?

Comment: actually i am getting this type of problem can you solve this ?

Comment: i'm using `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;` under `-viewWillAppear` and setting `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;` under  `-viewWillDisappear` and i dont experience this.. weird..

Comment: Please check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/37917633/1517506

Answer (score 9):

If you set

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES
```

iOS will sometimes generate three dots inside its generic back button. 
I solved the problem by setting the text on the generic back button to be empty and then I created my custom button. This is how I set the empty text:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton2;
```

And then I created my custom UIButton and placed it where I wanted it like this:

```
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 70/2-22, 44, 44)];
[backButton setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
backButton.tintColor = tintColor;
backButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-2, -15, 0, 0);


[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popCurrentViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to hide the `backButton`, you can just add custom back button, it will hide the default button.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(handleBack:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
}

- (void) handleBack:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: That's what I am trying to do now, even if it is not a perfect solution as the padding in te navigation bar will not be the same in ios6 and ios7. But thanks for your solution although I don't succeed for the moment to make appear this button again after the back animation.

Answer (score 2):

Just add these following lines in viewWillAppear method:

Swift:

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)`

Objective C:

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];`

That's all

Answer (score 1):

navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil

Answer (score 0):

Simpler swift version :

```
let emptyBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = emptyBackButton
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write any code just follow 4 simple step and you done it.

1. Select your Main.storyboard
2. Select Navigation Bar in Navigation Controller
3. Select Attributes Inspector
4. Clear Tint color

[image]